# No EditorOptionDefinition Export Found Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 I started getting the following error when trying to open C# files:

```
No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option name:
Tabs/ConvertTabsToSpaces
Parameter name: optionID
```

I was having no issues all morning until I closed and re-opened a C# solution I was working on when this error started. I checked and this error happens when I open any C# project on this computer. I also tried opening the same project from my other computer and it works fine, so this is not a project error.

I have not changed any VS settings, and I was just trying to open the package manager when this presented itself.

I am at a loss and Dr. Google is not of much help thus far.

Answer (score 613, accepted):

After a reboot and some more research I found this [post](http://www.rajapet.com/2014/02/when-the-editorpackage-does-not-load-correctly.html) from a blog. The error described is not the same error I am seeing, however, it was close enough to warrant a try.

Follow the steps:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open the folder: `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\`
   (in `C:\users\'%userName%'\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\`)
3. Rename the ComponentModelCache folder
4. Restart Visual Studio.

Visual studio will recreate the folder and all will be well with the world (or at least VS). I love a simple solution, and I hope its of use to anybody else who runs into this issue!

Comment: The easiest part of this answer is to located ComponenetModeCacheFolder. Cheers!! Thank you.

Comment: This helped to fix the issue in VS 2017, This should be informed to Visual Studio Team to fix in future releases.

Answer (score 25):

I had a same problem  I did small change for Jake Answer

```
 1 Close Visual Studio
 2 Search ComponentModelCache Folder
 3 Rename folder
 4 Restart the visual Studio
```

And it start to work

It happened to me again then this time I tried Web [Essentials 2013.5](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) then Its start to work. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 14):

Running windows 8.1, VS2013.3 and was able to find the folder.  Using the find function in 8.1 did not find the folder, but looking into the %APPDATA% folder I was directed to a Roaming folder.  Then by going one level up I did see the local folder in AppData.

The final path where I was able to find the folder was the same as mentioned above.
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0

Renaming the folder did work.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that answer is not necessarily correct. In my Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013 for Web (12.0.30723.00 Update 3), there was no ComponentModelCache folder.

Instead, what I did is ran all updates for VS2013 and then went to Control Panel/Programs and Features and performed a repair. Voila, that worked and I think may be a better overall solution.

Comment: For the guys down voting my answer, may I suggest you leave a comment on why I'm wrong or misguided. I tried to give an explanation that worked fine and didn't require manually deleting a directory.

Answer (score 6):

Yes I had this same problem with VS2013 and WIndows 7. Renamed folder

> C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0

Comment: Worked for me with Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Installing [Web Essentials 2013 for VS 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) as suggested here [Project does not load after installing visual studio 2013 update 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201777/project-does-not-load-after-installing-visual-studio-2013-update-2) in Sagar S.'s solution, worked for me with VS 2013 Update 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem,

Now I use Windows 8.1 and VS Express 2013 for web.
Renaming the folder didn't help as it didn't change when I re-started VS.
Repairing the programme didn't help nor did restarting the computer.

What worked for me was just a basic uninstall & reinstall, sometimes a bit of common sense is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Turning off a plugin called "Visual Assist" solved it for me.