# VS2013: Error Loading Solution ('JavascriptWebExtensionsPackage did not load correctly')

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 Professional just started throwing this error on me, in the middle of switching solutions.     A full reboot of the computer didn't resolve it.

Here's the error I see when I try loading a solution:
[image: main error]

Now, when I go look at the log file it suggests, I see this:

[image: SetSite failed]

> SetSite failed for package [JavaScriptWebExtensionsPackage]
>
> End package load [JavaScriptWebExtensionsPackage]

If I click "Yes" to continuing to show the message, and try loading up a file in the solution -- I get this message:

[image: NoEditorOptionDefinition export found]

Telling me that `No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option name: Tabs/ConvertTabsToSpaces - Parameter name: optionId`.

I really do not know what to make of this.   I didn't do anything except check in some files to TFS (which I do dozens of times a day, a week, a year).   The *only* thing I ever did differently that I never did before was attempt to view Source>Annotations on a file (I've never did that in my life with TFS/VS) about 10 minutes prior - but that worked fine and was just ducky.

So - any ideas why I'm getting this message - and how to resolve it without a fullblown re-install?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

So -- after posting this and adding that last screenshot (the No EditorOptionDefinition export... business) -- I decided to google on that phrase as well (the other key phrases brought me nothing).

It brought me to this page:
[No EditorOptionDefinition Export Found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893497/no-editoroptiondefinition-export-found-error)

Which actually fixed the problem.

In short:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open the `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\` folder
3. Rename or delete the `ComponentModelCache` folder
4. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Thankyou! Save much stress :-)

Comment: But seem all plugin should to reinstall.

Comment: Sorry, I renamed *Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ not sub dir ComponentModelCache , but all problem cleared.

Comment: I had the same issue in VS 2015 and your solution solved the problem.

Comment: I was not getting the EditorOptionDefinition Export Found Error, instead VS 2015 was crashing and closing, but the fix still worked for me.

Comment: The same issue after install the AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe,Thank you!

Comment: This didin't worked for me. :( I deleted the folder and the error remains

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, All i did was went to Control Panel and ran a Repair on VS 2013. Waited for it to complete and restart my computer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case above solution not work out but when I tried to delete everything from

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\

from above location then I restarted visual studio 2015 then it works fine.

Hope anyone having this issue may resolve deleting everything from 14.0 directory

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. Deleting %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ worked fine. I could not delete for permission reasons so had to delete from command line all files in 14.0.