# Error reading NuGet.config

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

So all of a sudden a few of the computers at my job stopped working with NuGet.
The problem started with following error.

[image]

So I went over and examined the Log file which gave me following errors

[Activitylog.xml](http://pastebin.com/CLC3WVFV) (layout in the question went haywire - pastebin link)

So naturally I went over to the global config of NuGet just to find it empty. So I reinstalled NuGet, deleted the folder, reinstalled. You know the normal way of doing thing. After finding out that it didn't work, I tried it several times over with rebooting, registry cleaning, etc..

Also tried this [VS2013: Error Loading Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573424/vs2013-error-loading-solution-javascriptwebextensionspackage-did-not-load-cor/25573496#25573496)

So after a few tries
I managed to get to this point. [image]

The funny thing about this issue, not all of our computers are having this problem, just certain ones. Anyway, I managed one time to get the right config that the NuGet tool window loaded correctly which gave me another error while building. (Mondays suck).

`Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Error reading 'FILEPATH\21_MES_ACC\CSD4.WPF4.011DSP\nuget.config'.`

So I'm not sure from this point how all these errors came to be and why not everybody is facing the same issue. Did someone face the same error and solved it? Do we need to reinstall things? Is this a NuGet issue? Is there a fix somewhere on the internet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there was an invisible whitespace in the nuget config file which was causing havoc