# Visual Studio 2015 WPF XAML Editor cannot open XAML files

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have recently updated from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (Professional). Everything works fine except the fact that I can't open XAML files - after clicking on any XAML file I get:

```
Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error.
```

It looks that XamlDesignerPackage hasn't been installed. 
XamlEditor entry doesn't exist under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0`\ and it exists under
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\` which may suggest that XAML Designer is not installed for this visual studio 2015.

I have tried everything:

- 4 reinstalls
- cleaning caches
- removing ComponentDataCache
- resetting settings.

In Visual Studio 2013 everything works fine. Is there a way to use XAMLEditor from VS2013? Do you have any ideas what I can do? I would be glad for any help since it prevents me from working. This is an error from ActivityLog.xml:

> 507 2016/04/04 13:15:58.450
>   Error VisualStudio SetSite
>   failed for package [XamlDesignerPackage][Method failed with unexpected
>   error code 50.]:{   at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType
>   resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle,
>   AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName,
>   ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object
>   exceptionContext)
>    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean
>   isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections,
>   Boolean isDirectory)
>    at
>   System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity..ctor(String fileName,
>   AccessControlSections includeSections)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.IO.AccessHelper.IsAccessibleByAllApplicationPackages(String
>   path)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Utils.HostAppPackageAclService.CheckAclsOnDirectory(String
>   directory)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Utils.HostAppPackageAclService.ValidateOrUpdateDirectoryAcls(String
>   directory)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Utils.HostAppPackageAclService.ValidateOrUpdateAclsNoPrompt(IEnumerable`1
>   paths)
>    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.Initialize()
>
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Package.XamlDesignerPackage.Initialize()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider
>   sp)}
>           {512BE089-83EC-4CC6-8483-CF16565AE209}
>
> ---
>
> 80131509
>           Method failed with unexpected error code 50.

**Edit:**

I have found that above `guid` exists in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\` under Editors entry. It looks like designer hasn't been installed because it exists in vs 2013. There must be a conflict.

Edit: I have removed both 2013 and 2015 and installed 2015 and getting the following message when running Visual Studio 2015:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994558/visual-studio-2015-c-sharp-xaml-designer-doesnt-load and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090719/view-designer-not-showing-up

Comment: @StepUp It's not exactly the same problem - it's WPF project and their solutions is to change target version which is not present in wpf project.

Comment: you cannot see XAML in XAML Designer? Could you post an image of your XAML Designer to clarify your question?

Comment: @StepUp When I click on any XAML file in a solution I get "Unexpected error" and it doesn't open the xaml file. It's more like a XAMLEditor not only XAML Designer because it prevents me from editing XAML files.

Comment: maybe you should just delete VS2013 and VS 2015? Then, at first install VS2015 and if you need install VS2013?

Comment: I didn't want to uninstall it, just to have at least one working environment but it may help. Will give it a try

Comment: @StepUp still doesn't work

Comment: Have you uninstalled `VS 2013` and `VS2015` completely and then install just VS 2015?

Comment: @StepUp yes and still getting exactly the same error. I've updated my original post to show what I get when I open vs

Comment: please, read these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893497/no-editoroptiondefinition-export-found-error and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573424/vs2013-error-loading-solution-javascriptwebextensionspackage-did-not-load-cor

Comment: @StepUp nothing helps - I am moving back to vs 2013. Thanks for your help but it seems to be more complicated

Comment: ask here. You have really nice question. I always was answered at the most complicated answer at MSDN WPF Forum. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=wpf

Comment: @StepUp thank you, will give it a try

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37100586/111794).

Comment: @ZevSpitz it doesn't work

Comment: I can only suggest that you vote for the already submitted issue through the Send Feedback menu option in Visual Studio, as I noted in my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36984909/111794). Hopefully, it will get more attention, the more votes it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with Visual Studio Update 3

Comment: still have this issue with `VS 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3` and `VS2017 VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.5+26730.16`. Me and two my colleagues

Answer (score 2):

From the ActivityLog.xml there is a clear indication that you have file access/permission issues. Those always manage to creep into providing us devs with un-needed issues. What I suggest you do is make sure you install VS as an administrator and also run it as Administrator.

I'm sure that will sort your issue out. Good luck.

Comment: In my case, just applying the appropriate permission to the project folder (and it's children) solved the issue.

Comment: @GabrielRainha please help me to solve the same issue. What folder have you used to apply permission? VS %appdata% or %programfiles% ? And what permission should be set ? It is  a pity that access denied error does not contain folder name. like any other file or folder exception.

Comment: @oleksa I believe I meant the solution folder. Right-click the solution on Visual Studio, click Open Folder in File Explorer, right click the folder on Windows Explorer, click Properties, go to Security and set Read/Write permission to your user. It's been a long time since I replied to this issue, though, so I might as well be mistaken.