# Error message with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 with Windows 7, when I want to edit C# code, it show me a error

> NO Editor option definition export found for the given option name Visual Studio

like at this picture

[image: http://ppt.cc/qPl36]
<sub>(source: [ppt.cc](http://ppt.cc/qPl36@.jpg))</sub>
.

Is something wrong with my Visual Studio?

I just change the path with the "project path " in the  tool/option/project/general. but I change back when it happen error.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open the folder: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\
3. Rename the ComponentModelCache folder
4. Restart Visual Studio.

Visual studio will recreate the folder and all will be well with the world (or at least VS). I love a simple solution, and I hope its of use to anybody else who runs into this issue!

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893497/no-editoroptiondefinition-export-found-error)