# "No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option name:TextViewHost/LineNumberMargin Parameter name:optionId"

Tags: c#, wix

I'm working with WiX installer and trying to open my Installer files  .wxs for editing and i'm getting a this  error.

> No EditorOptionDefinition export found for the given option
>   name:TextViewHost/LineNumberMargin  Parameter name:optionId

Comment: I am not able to find ComponentModelCache folder in my system.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893497/no-editoroptiondefinition-export-found-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893497/no-editoroptiondefinition-export-found-error)

Isnt it easier to google it than to create an account and ask?

Comment: hellogoodnight thank you for your comments but I already googled it and there very few solution which i have tried but yet not get resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps:

1.Close Visual Studio

2.Open the folder: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\

3.Rename the ComponentModelCache folder

4.Restart Visual Studio. Visual studio will recreate the folder and all will be well with the world (or at least VS).

Comment: This does actually helped me as well, Thank you for that. But could you please explain on what is the root cause here?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact issue where I was not able to open any files(code) .
The easiest way in which we can resolve issue is to download the visual studio web essentials .(http://vswebessentials.com/download)
Once you download you will be able to open your files and no error will be thrown.

thanks,
Abhimanyu