# Not able to create Qt project with Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm not able to create a Qt project with Visual Studio Community 2015 in Windows 10.

Steps I followed to setup QT with VS2015,

- Installed visual studio community 10
- Downloaded and installed QT for [VS2015](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.6.2.exe)
- Added QtPackage in VS2015 "Extensions and Updates", also added Qt version.

How I create new QT project

- I select "QT application" under Visual C++ templates, which prompts couple of Qt project options to create application, but at the last before creating a project visual studio throws error

***'C:\Users\users\AppData\Local\Temp\h451xhqd.vcproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.vcproj) is not supported by this version of the application.***

However, I'm able to create a project with QT creator. Any help or pointer will be helpful.

PS: I'm new to VisualC++ :)
Below are the similar SO question that didn't helped

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641063/qt-in-visual-studio-2015-cant-create-qt-project)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697354/1083135)
3. [A video link from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfEttsC1vEA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to create a QT project.

Actually problem was with VC++ setup and template files. These two link was very helpful to me.

1. Running setup mentioned in section "[Visual C++ : Project creation failure after Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3)"
2. [Renaming ComponentModelCache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23894744/303612)